# AOP Spring Wildcard dont work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

I'm Trying to learn AOP using this Tutorial:

[Spring Tutorial 28 - Pointcuts and Wildcard Expressions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7IdaLybg9A#t=10/)

I'm not using XML but annotation.

the problem occur when i use wildcards and not the direct words.

this code works great:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Before("execution(public String  get*())")
    public void loggingAdvice(){
        System.out.println("Advice run. Get Method Called");
    }
```

this code don't work:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Before("execution(* *  get*())")
    public void loggingAdvice(){
        System.out.println("Advice run. Get Method Called");
    }
```

and this is the main:

```
@Component
public class AopMain {
    private final static String xmlPath = "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/context.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(xmlPath);
        ShapeService shapeService = ctx.getBean("shapeService", ShapeService.class);
        System.out.println(shapeService.getCircle().getName());}
}
```

the Error i get is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.ConversionServiceExposingInterceptor] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting '(' at character position 15
execution(* *  get*())
               ^^^
```

does anyone know why it dosnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
@Before("execution(*  get*())")
public void loggingAdvice(){
    System.out.println("Advice run. Get Method Called");
}
```

one asterisk too much

Comment: I have tested this one. It works. The pointcut is 100% proper. Maybe the problem is because actually you are attaching this aspect to all of your beans (including spring services and others) and then some unpredictable things happen. I do not see the configuration. To simplify the case try to restrict the package to your own like that 
execution(* com.xyz.service.*.get*())

Comment: What is the meaning of wildcard (the first one) that starts with  execution `execution(*`

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
@Before("execution(*  get*())")
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the Below Explanition.It will give you better Idea about Wildcards in AOP:
Either You have to use * or .. inside the get(*) or get(..)

the execution of any method defined by the AccountService interface:
execution(* com.xyz.service.AccountService.*(..))

the execution of any method defined in the service package:
execution(* com.xyz.service.*.*(..))

the execution of any method defined in the service package or a sub-package:
execution(* com.xyz.service..*.*(..))